# Como "dar" y luego "guardar" creditos por dar click en un div

Tags: php, mysql

Bueno, tengo esta idea, mostrar unos anuncios que hice yo, y cada anuncio te da x creditos, y luego esos creditos se pueden cambiar para desbloquear unas opciones del menu de la página, la cosa, es que probe, busqué y no encontré nada, tampoco se en concreto como buscar lo que quiero.
Tengo un login y registro básico, que si lo necesitan los paso.
por ahora solo dejo lo que hice, que no funciona:
`<h1>Creditos $ 0.0</h1>`

Aqui tendría que poner los creditos que se hayan acumulado.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Creditos por ver $<?php echo  "0,0$ram2" ?></h3>
      <p>anuncio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Creditos por ver $<?php echo  "0,0$ram4" ?></h3>
      <p>anuncio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Creditos por ver $<?php echo  "0,0$ram6" ?></h3>
      <p>anuncio</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Donde `$ram2,$ram4,$ram6` son solamente numeros ramdom.

```
  <?php
// $ram1=mt_rand(0,5);
$ram2=mt_rand(1,3);
// $ram3=mt_rand(0,5);
$ram4=mt_rand(1,3);
// $ram5=mt_rand(0,5);
$ram6=mt_rand(1,3);

?>
```

Yo se que los creditos tendrían que estar en la base de datos, pero estoy tratando de evitar eso, ya que solamente es un contador respecto a los anuncios que den click. 
Espero que se haya entendido. Cualquier cosa que no entiendan de la pregunta me avisa asi edito. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo la salvedad de que tu enunciado no me es del todo claro *(guardo pero no permanente y entonces tengo login/registro pero el próximo logueo empezaría con los clics en cero...)*,
creo entender que lo que necesitás es un "contador de clics".

Un [ejemplo](https://iscelialejandro.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/un-contador-de-clicks/) - muy sencillo - podría ser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contador de clicks</title>
    <script>
    var i = 0
    function clickLink() {
        i++;
        if (i == 1) {
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = i;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = i;
        }
    }
    function Reset() {
        i = 0;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = i;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:clickLink();">Click aquí</a>
    <p>Clicks <span id="clicks">0</span></p>
    <a href="javascript:Reset();">Reset</a>
</body>
```

Básicamente, como su nombre lo dice, es un contador de clics.  Para este nivel de simplicidad con un poco de Javascript, sería más que suficiente.

Ahora bien, sin algún tipo de almacenamiento permanente todavía sería posible (ya que hablás de login y registro) salvar temporalmente algunos datos y para eso podrías usar una sesión de PHP, pero como aclaré arriba, el usuario eventualmente perdería sus clics.

Saludos,

Comment: Ahora estudio bien ese codigo, pero te explico resumidamente, quiero que cada click en estos "anuncios" de x creditos, y eso guardarlo, e ir sumandolo si el usuario sigue haciendo clicks, y si por ejemplo, vuelve en unos dias, siga teniendo el contador, que sea unico por usuario, pero por lo que veo no es tan sencillo, asi que, podría ser almacenarlo en la base de datos del usuario, pero tendria que pasar toda mi estructura de login, registro y panel de control o no?

Comment: Si vas a guardar los clics en una base de datos vas a tener que usar ajax. Si fuera el caso, seguramente vas a tener que usar algo como jquery que si bien no es indispensable, te simplifica el trabajo.